# Difference between bivariate exponential family and bivariate elliptical family

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, elliptical-distribution

I'm studying the [elliptical family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution) and I'd like to know the principal differences between the bivariate [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) and elliptical family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a result in [Kelker (1970, Sankhya A)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution#CITEREFFangKotzNg1990), the Normal distribution is [the only intersection](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1403038) between elliptical and exponential families. I recommend reading this fundamental paper about elliptical families, which are rarely covered by textbooks, as opposed to exponential families.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about the class of normal distributions being the only class which is both an elliptical family and an exponential family?

Comment: Have you read Kelker's paper?